# Is there a way to load mutiple ModelDriven models for one action class in Struts2?

Tags: struts2, action, model-driven

Is there a way to load mutiple ModelDriven models for one action class or swtich the model on one action class in struts2?

Comment: why you need multiple model for a single action? the second part of your question is not clear enough, can you rephrase that?

Answer (score 1):

You can return arbitrary objects through `ModelDriven` by using `ModelDriven<Object>`. This is often used in CRUD actions to return either a list of domain objects, or a single domain object.

Alternatively, a model object may be composited from other objects, for example, a `UserModel` might have both `List<User>` and `User` properties, each filled with data when appropriate. The properties don't need to be the same type, though, so a model might have `User` properties, and a list of `Headline`s or something.